# Arabic text with PDF form fields C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I have a template pdf file with Form Fields
i use [iText](https://itextpdf.com) to insert values from database to the fields

Here is the Code

```
string NewFile = "vac" + cellValue;
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("vacTemplate2.pdf");
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(NewFile, FileMode.Create));

AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField("No", dt.Rows[0]["MilitaryNo"].ToString());
pdfFormFields.SetField("Name", dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString());
pdfFormFields.SetField("Rank", dt.Rows[0]["RankName"].ToString());
pdfFormFields.SetField("Nat", "NewNat");// dt.Rows[0]["NatName"].ToString());
pdfFormFields.SetField("VacPeriod", dt.Rows[0]["Period"].ToString());


pdfStamper.Close();
```

it works fine with the numbers and English text but with arabic text the text is hidden behind the field i had to click on the field to show the values
the language show correctly

it opens correct on Microsoft edge but on the print the arabic fields disappear

Edge Image
[image]

chrome
[image]

Adobe Before Click
[image]

Adobe after click
[image]

and the print on adobe is still hide the values

System :Win10-64 - Visual Studio 2015 - C# Winforms

Note : Template File Creates using Adobe Acrobat from Word file

Comment: Please do not use iText from Sourceforge. It is not updated there any more and it will be deleted soon. Use iText from NuGet (.NET) or Maven (Java).

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: Runtime Version : v2.0.50727  -- Version :5.5.12.0